# Splitting the file name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

good morning guys,

I have the following dataFrame

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|co_tipo_arquiv|filename                                                |count_tipo_arquiv|
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|05            |hdfs://spbrhdpdev1.br.experian.local:8020/files/files_01|2                |
|01            |hdfs://spbrhdpdev1.br.experian.local:8020/files/files_02|2                |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to get only the file name in the filename column
getting that way

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|co_tipo_arquiv|filename                                                |count_tipo_arquiv|
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|05            |files_01                                                |2                |
|01            |files_02                                                |2                |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I thought about doing a split, but I don't know how to get the last value

```
split(col("filename"), "/")
```

but .last dont work

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|co_tipo_arquiv|filename                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+    
|05            |[hdfs:, , spbrhdpdev1.br.experian.local:8020,files, files_01]|
|01            |[hdfs:, , spbrhdpdev1.br.experian.local:8020,files, files_02]|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **`Spark-2.4+`**:

We can use **`element_at`** function to get last index of array.

**`1.Using element_at function:`**

```
df.withColumn("filename",element_at(split(col("filename"),"/"),-1)).show()
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|co_tipo_arquiv|filename|count_tipo_arquiv|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|            05|files_01|                2|
//|            01|files_02|                2|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
```

For **`Spark < 2.4`**:

**`2.Using substring_index function:`**

```
df.withColumn("filename",substring_index(col("filename"),"/",-1)).show()
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|co_tipo_arquiv|filename|count_tipo_arquiv|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|            05|files_01|                2|
//|            01|files_02|                2|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
```

**`3.Using regexp_extract function:`**

```
df.withColumn("filename",regexp_extract(col("filename"),"([^\\/]+$)",1)).show()
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|co_tipo_arquiv|filename|count_tipo_arquiv|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
//|            05|files_01|                2|
//|            01|files_02|                2|
//+--------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: element_at  I can't use because the project use spark 2.3